# Log file not produced until WebLogic is restarted

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, ear

I'm working on the development of an application that is deployed on WebLogic 10.3. It is packaged as an EAR and includes one module. The application works fine by itself but I am faced with issue related to logging.

I am using Log4j. The library is included in the EAR file and log4j.xml is placed under JAR module. So the config location is the following:

`A.ear/B.jar/log4j.xml`

Log4j config is following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss} %p %C{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="DRFA" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file"
        value="servers/AdminServer/logs/EJB.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss} %p %C{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="com.companyname.ejb" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DRFA" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.companyname.results" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DRFA" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.companyname.marketdata" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DRFA" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</logger>


<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</root>
```

When I build and deploy EAR (using Maven and customized WebLogic plugin) and call application no log file appears. But if I restart WebLogic everything is fine.

WebLogic is running under Windows 7 in domain mode with single node.

I'd like to know if there is some way to make the log appear without weblogic restart (since it can cause issues on production environment)?

**Update:** Also I'd like to know what is the reason of such behavior (i.e. why the log file  is not created right after application deployment)? Is this an issue with Weblogic, log4j or with their coupling? I've tried to find the answer in the Oracle documentation, but no luck for now.

Comment: Try taking out the log4j.xml from the EAR and put it in a directory which is part of server classpath (ex: $DOMAIN_HOME/lib). This will make the server to read the log4j during startup itself and if any modifications are required to the log levels, this log4j.xml can be changed without having to re-deploy the application. Take a look at the [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140393/multiple-applications-with-multiple-log4j-xml-in-weblogic/13141827#13141827)

Comment: There are few other ear files deployed on Weblogic, in your post you said that: "I don't think its possible to have different log4j.xml files for different applications deployed on the same WebLogic server unless the log4j.xml files are packaged with ear itself." So probably it is not the case.

Comment: My point is, its always better to have the log4j.xml outside of your ear file. Could you give a try?

Comment: Oh wait, I see that you are saying your server will also have other ear files deployed. Again its better to have log4j outside of the ear but have one log4j for all the ears. Each ear (application) can use different types of loggers defined in log4j. The reason why I keep saying that log4j should be outside is: when production operations team need to increase/decrease log level, they literally have to extract the ear, modify the log4j and re-deploy the ear which I think is NOT a good idea.

Comment: I see your point regarding log level modification, but current issue is that we have no logs at all on stage and prod. We have strict deadlines for new version release. For now I have to figure out if it is possible to make logs appear with minimal changes in deployment activities (i.e. no server restart and putting log config somewhere outside the EAR) and code base, so we can release new version in time. If it is impossible then probably hot and cold servers approach (mentioned by [eis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/365237/eis) in the first answer) should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any quick configuration solution, so code change was required.

I've added Weblogic Application Lifecycle listener as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2045531/1806341). Its postStart() method initializes log4j explicitly through DOMConfigurator and now logs appear right after application deployment.

The are few alternatives how configuration can be initialized. One of them was mentioned in [eis' post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274643/1806341) and another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757743/1806341). But I've choose listener in order to keep single module in EAR and in order to avoid issues with singleton EJB on cluster environment (i.e. I am not sure if Weblogic will create singleton on each node or just one instance per cluster).

Also in order to prevent environment changes for local and dev environment, I am using internal log4j.xml (i.e. placed within ear file) there.

For stage and prod - external config file is specified (in Maven profile).

External file is monitored by log4j so changes will be automatically applied without any redeployments or restarts.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that adding weblogic application lifecycle listener is a WL-specific solution, using a servlet would've been a standard one.

Comment: @eis, I completely agree with your point, but project that I am working on is already highly coupled with WL (e.g. we are heavily using OSB), so in my case it does not matter if solution is general or WL specific.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- In prod environment, you probably want to have your log configuration outside app packages, so you can change log levels without redeployment.
- You should plan for production to be able to handle restarts. We usually have hot and cold servers, so load can be balanced and servers restarted when doing the deployment.

About the issue, if you want to, you could specify a servlet that is run on startup of app and configures your log4j. Something like:

web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>YourServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Servlet

```
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void init(final ServletConfig config)
      throws ServletException
    {
        final java.net.URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("Log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(url);
    }
}
```

There's also an [example on the web](http://www.javatastic.com/2007/08/22/initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application/) about using a servlet context listener.

---

Edit. as to why this happens, weblogic logging mechanism is initiated by default on startup with these kind of settings:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dlog4j.configuration=file:<path>/log4j.properties
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger   
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true
```

so if you just redeploy your app without restarting the server, these settings will not be used -> logging will not get initiated.

Comment: Thanks for response, but currently there is only EJB module present in the EAR file. And I'm not sure if adding of WEB module to initialize log4j is the best idea. Anyway if I'd not be able to find other solution I'll try to use this one.

Comment: @igor added a note as to why this happens.